# Extracting reviews from Google play store app website

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-play, screen-scraping

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

class FindByXpathCss():
    # Declaring variables
    Reviews = []  # List to store final set of reviews
    reviewText = []  # List to store reviews extracted from XPath
    reviewFullText = []

    # Chromedriver path
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"F:\Chrome-webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()

    baseUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true"

    driver.get(baseUrl)
    # driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,300);")
    # Scrolling down
    for i in range(20):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, i)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    # To click on Show more button
    #btnShowMore = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]''/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/span').click()
    # Scrolling to top
    for j in range(10):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP, j)

    #for i in range(10):
    review_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'')][contains(text(),'Full Review')]")
    single_review_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'')][contains(text(),'Full Review')]")
    #time.sleep(1)
```

The div html tag having 2  tags, one is having jsname as 'fbQN7e' which is there for holding the bigger reviews and those reviews will have button called "Full Review". Another one span within the same div html tag is 'bN97Pc' which is there to hold smaller reviews which wont have 'Full review' button at the end of this review. I couldn't get reviews of both types of span. Here I tried to write reviewFullText list directly to dataframe, but getting only element datatype, not text. I don't know why this too happening.

```
    for btn in review_btn:
        btn.click()
        reviewFullText = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[jsname='fbQN7e']")

    #if(single_review_btn.is_enabled()==False):
        #reviewText = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[jsname=\"bN97Pc\"]")
    ##else:
        #pass

    # Iterating each reviews and appending into list Reviews
    for txtreview in reviewText:
        reviewFullText.append(txtreview.text)

    print(len(reviewFullText))

        # Writing the list values into csv file
    df = pd.DataFrame(reviewFullText)
        #df = pd.DataFrame({'Reviews': 'Reviews'}) #'Sentiment': 'null'})
    df.to_csv('Reviews.csv', index=True, encoding='utf-8')

    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your solution to retrieve all review from the page.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
class FindByXpathCss():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.maximize_window()
        baseUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true"
        driver.get(baseUrl)

        scrolls = 3
        while True:
            scrolls -= 1
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
            time.sleep(3)
            if scrolls < 0:
                break

        buttonClick = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'')][contains(text(),'Full Review')]")))
        for element in buttonClick:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

        reviewText = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='UD7Dzf']")))


        for textreview in reviewText:
            print textreview.text

        reviewText = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='UD7Dzf']")))

        # reviewText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='UD7Dzf']")
        for textreview in reviewText:
            print textreview.text
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Here we will get 2 problems:- 1) Full  Review button should be clicked wherever it is applicable and then review must be scraped , if Full review button is not visible, review text must resided in diff span ID, we should get that too, 

In your code is Full review not clicked and review is also not extracted completely, anyway thanks for your time. if possible please try for my below logic:-

If the review having Full review button, it should be clicked and review must be extracted and added into list,  
If the review doesnt have Full rev btn, review must be extracted and added to list..

Comment: @RaghuYoutuber : I have extracted entire review if its present

Comment: @RaghuYoutuber : please aceept answer